# error in Version string 'v1.4': version number does not start with digit;

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install [Bulkr](http://clipyourphotos.com/bulkr), an Adobe AIR application for downloading Flick photos in Ubuntu 11.04 but the installation fails with an error dialogue box that says **"The application could not be installed. Try installing it again. If the problem persists, contact the application author. Error #1"**.

Main highlight of the error log files are:

1. Error: Only root can install the application"
2. Error: dpkg: error processing /tmp/FlashTmp.HhLatV/setup.deb (--install)......error in Version string 'v1.4': version number does not start with digit;

I am able to install & run Bulkr in Ubuntu 10.04. So, is this an issue with Bulkr application version number not being compatible for Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Have you used 'sudo' in order to make the installation?

Comment: @Pavlos G ~ My user a/c has Administrator access & the setup file is 'Bulkr-v1.4.air'. Since I have Adobe AIR installed, '.air' files are automatically opened by Adobe Air Application installer.

Comment: Check this link, it might help you a bit:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/842672?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

'v1.4' is not a valid version number for a .deb package. Previous versions of dpkg just ignored that but now it's an error. See https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/147533

Contact the package developer and ask nicely to correct the version number.